# How do I change the DoF settings of the active camera using python?

Tags: python, scripting, camera, depth-of-field

I want to change the DoF distance of the **active** camera in a scene using a script. So far I have written:

```
bpy.data.cameras[0].dof_distance = distance #"distance" is the variable I want to use
```

But that sets the DoF distance for the camera that comes first in the outliner (alphabetically), which is not necessarily the active one.

So I tried getting the *active camera* property from the scene settings using

```
bpy.context.scene.camera.dof_distance = distance
```

But that does not work at all, because this method only returns the object, but not the "camera-properties" (as far as I get it).

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is it:

```
obj_camera.data.dof_distance = distance
```

This seem to always choose the correct camera, even if the datablock is named differently.

Comment: @brockmann  using eg above `obj_camera` is an object (in `bpy.data.objects`) of type CAMERA, so `obj_camera.data` is a member of `bpy.data.cameras`.  They do not need to have the same name, (which is the issue with your answer).

Answer (score 3):

[`bpy.context.scene.camera`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=scene%20camera#bpy.types.Scene.camera) returns the active camera in the scene. In order to change your *Depth of Field* settings use the [Console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/python_console.html), [Python Tooltips](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/getting_started/help.html#tooltips) or the [API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Camera.html?highlight=dof_distance#bpy.types.Camera.dof_distance) to find each corresponding property.

```
>>> active_cam = bpy.context.scene.camera
>>> bpy.data.cameras[active_cam.name].
                                      angle
                                      angle_x
                                      angle_y
                                      dof_distance
                                      dof_object
                                      ...
>>> bpy.data.cameras[active_cam.name].dof_distance = 7
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this leads to another problem: http://imgur.com/a/KySFk The settings of a camera and the "camera-object" can hold a different name.... In that case the script does not work...